# How to update my Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have visual studio code 1.47.0. When I run it these days, it keeps saying "There is an available update." When I click on Download update, it takes me to https://code.visualstudio.com/ and I downloaded version 1.47.2.

How do I now do the update? When I click on the .deb file for 1.47.2, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/982407/how-to-update-software-installed-via-deb-file

Comment: Not a stellar duplicate, but it shows yow how to install a package with `dpkg`.

Comment: For me, ignoring the message from vscode, and using Software Updater of Ubuntu worked.

Comment: @triplee: I tried the answer from Ankit Chauhan and it worked so I haven't tried the solution you pointed out yet. Next time, I'll try that and see how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Both answers basically amount to the same thing. The Ask Ubuntu answer shows how to use the `apt` front end, whereas the duplicate uses bare `dpkg` directly. If you are a beginner, `apt` is probably nicer, as it can pull in new dependencies etc.